# Should be the file name of a protocol same with protocol name in definition?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning IOS development, found a protocol file, it is "ElementsDataSourceProtocol.h" , while the protocol name defined in this file is "ElementsDataSource".  As this truth, I think the file name of a protocol can be different from the protocol name.  But can anyone give same detailed explanation for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the protocol can be different from the name of the file. The actual name that matters for the runtime is the name on your protocol declaration. The file name matters to the compiler when it's trying to find the declaration. It's a good practice to keep consistency on the name, because it will be more intuitive to find a protocol definition inside a header of the protocol name, or inside the relevant file (UITableView has UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource inside its header).